# Rasterizing only the border of a vector polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization, nodata, gdal-rasterize

I have a layer of very 3 x 3 m square polygons. I would like to rasterize just the border of the squares, so the interior cells just have 'nodata' values, and you can see layers below it. When I process this with `rasterize` in QGIS, the whole square comes out black. Any way to do this?

[image: parameters]

[image: result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Convert polygons to lines.
2. Buffer the lines.
3. Rasterize the buffer.

*Left: original with initial polygon (red hached), line around polygon (black) and buffer (blue). Right: rasterized (black), initial, red hached polygons included for reference/visualization purpose:*
[image]