# Create Binary Layer from a shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, masking

I have an image `Image.tif` and a shapefile `Water.shp` (Several polygons) such that the polygons are all in the images boundaries.

I want to create a binary layer such that the layer has a 1 value on the polygons locations and 0 value everywhere else (but only in the image boundaries).

How can I do this in QGIS (3.18) ?

Comment: Does this help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408085/88814 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Rasterize* tool (Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to Raster). Here, you can set `A fixed value to burn` to `1` and `Pre-initialize the output image with value`to `0`. The other parameters need to be selected depending on what you need (extent/resolution etc).

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just to add for completion, for the created raster to have the size of the original image, in rasterize, Output Extent > Calculate from layer and select the wanted image.