# Give blank areas surrounding raster polygons value of zero

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

Just a query that I am trying to remember. I did this a few months ago and now can't recall how.
It's driving me mad

Say you have x number of seperate polygons across the study area (different values or weights) and you convert them to a single raster layer to use in a weighted overlay. Suppose you want to give the surrounding area of this raster a value of zero so they are all joined in one layer. And the layer encompasses the entire study area.

If you have a study area boundary & a another raster layer covering the entire scene, how do you create a layer where the seperate polygons are surrounded by the raster value zero as if islands in a raster lake.

Comment: It's QGIS and not ArcGIS and the problem is a bit different, however maybe the principles of the solutions linked in what follows could give you some ideas that could work in ArcGIS in a similar fashion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408064/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408085/88814

Comment: Use con() tool to set background values